# Building a simple C++ project in gradle 4+

Tags: c++, gradle

How can I build with Gradle a simple C++ project with the following components:

- Two units with headers, e.g, unit1.h, unit1.cpp, unit2.h, unit2.cpp.
- Two alternative main programs, e.g, main1.cpp, main2.cpp, which use unit1 and unit2.
- I would like to build it using clang++-5.0, which is installed on my Ubuntu system.

What Gradle file should I use in order to build and run each main program in turn, e.g, like:

```
gradle run main1
gradle run main2
```

? I read the Gradle docs, and all I found was [this example](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/native_software.html#sec:building_an_executable), but I did not understant how to change it to my project.